# Two special cases of NOT using the restrictive « ne ... que »

Tags: usage, négation

> 1. J'ai très peu de souvenirs de l'époque. Je me rappelle **seulement** **que** je ne sortais pas beaucoup.

I started off by saying « Je **ne** me rappelle **que que** je ne sortais ... », then I realised that I couldn't possibly use two « que »s in a row. If you’re planning to use the conjunction « que {that} » later on in a sentence, is it necessary to think ahead and avoid using the restrictive « ne ... que » in favour of « seulement, uniquement »?

> 2. La guerre a ravagé les quais. J'ai bien peur qu'il **ne** reste **plus** un seul bateau en état de prendre la mer.

I’m tempted to say « ... qu'il **ne** reste **plus qu**'un seul bateau ... » or « ... qu'il **ne** reste **qu**'un seul bateau ... ». So I’m not sure why you can omit « que » in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oups, it is simply that this are not examples of the restrictive *ne ...que*.

In first sentence, *seulement* is used to replace a *ne ... que*, because effectively you cannot use two following rows. At most you could use:

> Je ne me rappelle que du fait que je ne sortais pas beaucoup.

but it requires the *du fait que* expression that make the sentence heavier.

But in second one it would mean different things:

> J'ai bien peur qu'il ne reste plus un seul bateau en état de prendre la mer.

No boat can sail here, because we use the *ne ... plus* negation

> J'ai bien peur qu'il ne reste plus **qu'** un seul bateau en état de prendre la mer.

One boat can sail, because we use the restrictive *ne ... que* and *plus* is only here to insist in the sense of *only*.

Comment: +1 In addition to the fact that adding a 2nd “que” in the boat example would change the meaning, a secondary reason “why you can omit the que” in that example could be that the 1st clause of the boat example, unlike the 1st clause in example #1, is not restricted/doesn't need a restrictive “que,” & therefore doesn't present the same issue found in ex. 1. (cf:“Je n’ai [bien] peur que [de la possibilité] qu'il ne reste plus un seul.” Also, can the “que” of a restrictive “ne..que” ever serve also as the “que” that introduces clause 2 (eg: ex. 1=“Je ne me rappelle que je ne sortais pas”)? Thanks!