# "ne" that translates as "only"?

Tags: négation

i've seen the following sentence: "Je ne suis riche que de mes amis" (it's from a song).

As i understand it translates as "I'm rich only from my friends",
when you add the "pas" - it translates literally (which ofc doesn't make sense) - "I am not rich that of my friends"

so, why when adding "ne" without the "pas" the meaning is changed like that? is this some kind of a rule? (ne without pas is always "only")?

Comment: It's "ne que" not "ne" alone. I expect the answer to [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/22644/358) should answer yours as well. A search on the site with "ne que" will return more answers to your question.

Comment: Never be surprised to find that "que" has more meanings than expected. :D In sentences like this, when I'm forced to do a word-for-word translation (e.g. for a student who has trouble seeing the structure), I translate it as "but" or "except" and that gets close to a natural translation. "I'm not rich except for my friends."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *ne* without *pas* doesn't mean "only" - *ne ... que* does.

So the translation is "I'm rich only from my friends" (I'm rich only thanks to my friends, thanks to friendship.)

Comment: ahh! j'ai compris, Merci!

Comment: I don't think the translation is accurate. I would translate as _my only wealth is my friends_. I don't think _thanks to_ is appropriate here.

Comment: ye well i can relate to that, alot of french sentences are not translated directly to english, but i understood the context.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate the sentence as:

> My only wealth is my friends.

It is not possible to add *pas* in the sentence *Je ne suis riche que de mes amis*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the 'ne' in this phrase is not technically necessary, and since you say it comes from a song, might only be there for artistic reasons.

*Je suis riche que de mes amis* will be understood the same.

Additional note: both forms are a little bit stilted and contain some measure of poetic license. Drawing 'rules' from such phrases is not the best idea.

Comment: ye, i've read that there's not always proper french in songs, so its not a good way to learn.
thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Falc: _Je **ne** suis riche que de mes amis_ is much better :-) No reason to drop that **ne**.